# Populating NSTableView in OS X Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm learning to develop OS X application. I created a simple application that populates a table with itens. I've been trying to populate my NSTableView with no success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've got an array of 3 itens. The example is very simple.

Here is the code on github:

https://github.com/mcand/TableViewMacExample

Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: Did you set the dataSource property of NSTableView?

Comment: Yes. I've done like this:

[self.tableView setDataSource:self];

That is, the class implements the callbacks for populating the table.

Comment: Does the NSTableView Cell-based? Or View-based?

Comment: I don't know much about this. I've uploaded the code on github. I think it's view-based..

Comment: Open Attributes Inspector of NSTableView instance in the Nib-file. Find "Content Mode" property. It must be set of type Cell-based.

Comment: You'll want to implement the tableview delegate as well as the datasource.

Comment: Thank you. I've made it last night. I had to implement the delegate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use `-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` delegate method your cell must be the subclass of NSCell-class. And NSTableView must be Cell-based as well.

Comment: There's much more to it than that.